# JavaScript Object to replicate an object

Tags: javascript

Working on a Javascript lesson and I'm stuck trying to figure out how to answer/understand how to complete this question wanted to know if anyone could help.

```
 function Container(param) {
      var person = {
      firstName: 'Jimmy',
      lastName: 'Smith',
      get fullName() {
      return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
      },
    set fullName (name) {
       var words = name.toString().split(' ');
       this.firstName = words[0] || '';
       this.lastName = words[1] || '';
   }
  }
 }

  // Attempting to clone private getter don't know how to access it.

     function objectClone(person) {

       var orginal = person //Trying to access the private method

       var clone = function cloneObj { Object.assign({}, original); }

       clone.prototype.spillSecret = function() { alert(this.getfullName()); }

     ;}
```

Comment: SO is not a homework help service. You need to make an attempt to solve it yourself. If you get stuck, post what you tried and we'll help you fix it.

Comment: trying to wrap my ahead around on understanding the question. and it's not homework bud, just trying to learn JS

Comment: That's the same thing. Isn't there anything in the lesson that prepares you to answer the question?

Comment: Updated the question, I don't think my code is even close, but basically it went over closures and public, private, and priveleged. But spoke nothing about cloning objects

Comment: Have you learned about `Object.assign()` yet?

Comment: I didn't.. looked it up though so would I would set a var like var copy = Object.assign({},"Specific Variable");

Comment: That will copy the normal properties. The properties that are only accessible with `get` methods will have to be copied explicitly in your code.

Comment: I've updated the code, hopefully I'm getting closer, so from setting an var get method, I can then use the  var copy = Object.assign({},"Specific Variable");  ?

Answer (score 0):

```
var Person = function(person){
    var name = 'John Doe';
    function copy(){
        var newPerson = Object.assign({}, person);
        Object.defineProperty(newPerson, 'name', {
            get: function() { return name; },
            set: function(newName){ if(typeof newName !== 'string') {console.error('invalid name')} else name = newName},
            enumerable: true,
            configurable: true
        });
        return newPerson;
    }
    return copy();
};

var person1 = {
    age: 20,
    location: 'India'
}
var person2 = Person(person1);
var person3 = Person(person1);
person3.name = 1234;        // invalid name
person3.name = 'Mr. India';
console.log(person1.name);  // undefined
console.log(person2.name);  // John Doe
console.log(person3.name);  // Mr. India
```

Comment: How does this clone an object? It looks like it's just a constructor for making a new object.

Comment: I still don't see where you're cloning anything. You should have a function that takes `obj1` as an argument and returns `obj2` as the value.

Comment: Yeah i just wrote the sample code with static object obj. I think this is enough to move on. You can suggest what better you know.

Comment: The whole point of the question is about copying objects, not creating new objects from scratch. I don't know the answer to the question, but I don't see how this helps in any way.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Object.assign` to copy the normal properties, and then copy the special properties by hand after:

```
copy = Object.assign({}, original);
copy.year = original.year;
```

But this doesn't use a closure anywhere, so I'm not sure if it's what your tutorial is looking for.

Comment: Okay I'm a little lost so sorry, but thanks for your patience with this. So basically original was the original object I want to copy, Can't I use this same method in a private constructor? The closure would come in by creating a function that calls the "copy" which is the Object.assign?  I might be wayyy off base here

Comment: I don't see why you couldn't use this code in a constructor.

Comment: Sorry for the late response but I updated my code wanted to know if this was going in the right direction